# How to retrieve the MAX length for a Field defined in Table creation

Tags: sql

I created a table with the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `definition` 
(
    name_sha256 CHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
    id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
     measure_name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL 
)
```

and I want to check the upper bound of the field `measure_name`.

I explored around and only saw options to fetch the max value from existing rows by using

```
SELECT MAX((LENGTH(measure_name)) 
FROM definition
```

which returns 50 based current values in the table but I expect to see the 256.

Would like to get help for retrieving the max bound

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the official definition of the column, then you would use the metadata tables.  Many databases use the standard SQL views for this purpose, which would look like:

```
select c.*
from information_schema.columns c
where c.table_name = 'definition' and
      c.column_name = 'measure_name';
```

You may also need to take the schema name into account as well.